# Prevent SMIL animation from pausing when switching between browser tabs

Tags: javascript, css-animations, svg-animate, smil, visibilitychange

### How to prevent SMIL animation from pausing when switching between browser tabs?

I have SVG clock that is animated using `<animatetransform>`. When you switch to another tab animation freezes and don't catch up to where it should be.
I want this animation to either run smoothly when page is not visible or to pause and catch up when the page is visible again. I can convert this to CSS animation, it doesn't matter.

Here's a simplified code for seconds hand:

**HTML:**

```
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500" fill="none" stroke="#000">
<!-- ... -->
  <path id="Sec" stroke="#000" stroke-width="14" d="M0 0v-220">
    <animatetransform fill="freeze" additive="sum" attributename="transform" dur="60s" from="0" repeatcount="indefinite" to="360" type="rotate" />
  </path>
<!-- ... -->
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```
const date = new Date()
const sec = date.getSeconds()
document.getElementById('Sec').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${(sec * 360 / 60) % 360})`)
```

I know how to use `Page Visibility API` to pause things but how to prevent them from doing so is incomprehensible for me.

Comment: Using the `Page Visibility API` you can add or remove a class which will set all `animation-play-state` properties in CSS to `paused`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured that one out.

When the page is hidden the animation is paused with `animationsPaused()`.

When the page is visible again the script:

1. gets new date
2. resets animation clock with `setCurrentTime(0)`
3. updates `<path>` `transform` attribute
4. starts animation with `unpauseAnimations()`

**HTML:**

```
   <svg id="Watch" viewbox="-250 -250 500 500" fill="none" stroke="#000">
     <!-- ... -->
     <path id="Sec" stroke="#000" stroke-width="14" d="M0 0v-220">
       <animatetransform fill="freeze" additive="sum" attributename="transform" dur="60s" from="0" repeatcount="indefinite" to="360" type="rotate" />
     </path>
     <!-- ... -->
   </svg>
```

**JS:**

```
   const svg = document.getElementById('Watch')
   let date = new Date()
   const watch = () => {
     document.getElementById('Sec').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${(date.getSeconds() * 360 / 60) % 360})`)
   }
   window.requestIdleCallback(() => watch())
   document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
     if (document.hidden) svg.pauseAnimations()
     else {
       date = new Date()
       svg.setCurrentTime(0)
       watch()
       svg.unpauseAnimations()
     }
   })
```